# iOS and implementation of SQLite's FTS

Tags: ios, sqlite, full-text-search

When was SQLite3's FTS implemented in the standard iOS library? I know it's not available on iOS 3.*, but I'm seeing its effect on iOS 4.2.1, iOS 4.3.5 and iOS 5.0.1.

Is it also available in iOS 4.0? I have no easy way to test this, and I haven't located any references in Google.

Answer (score 0):

http://regularrateandrhythm.com/regular-rate-rhythm-blog/sqlite3-fts-in-IOS4.html

The author says it's in 4.0

Comment: Does he? I'm familiar with the article, but I don't see where he says this.